# apply KMeans to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, k-means

[DatasetImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRrXn.png)

[DatasetImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx5Li.png)

```
#KMEANS
import collections
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.002)

kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(X_train)
labels = kmeans.predict(X_test)
//X and y in train_test_split stands for:

X=newTotalDataset.drop('identifier',axis=1)
y=newTotalDataset['identifier']
```

I have a data frame with 44 feature and 30000 rows

print(collections.Counter(labels)). the last one is an identifier that says if the row is assigned to a person 1 or to a person 0.
I splitter my dataset in training and test, and removed my last feature.

The problem is when I print "labels", because it says me that all rows belongs to person 0

the result of the counter of 0 and 1 in label is this:
    Counter({0: 103})

How it's possibile? what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your labels before prediction you want to do supervised learning and you don't use the good algorithm, please take a look at some models like :

- Logistic regression
- random forest classifier
- SVM Classifier

and others

Comment: Try to set `shuffle=True` in train_test_split, maybe your data are ordered

Comment: Yes it has what?

Comment: identifier  
46364                   0.0  
30752                   0.0  
22494                   0.0  
18126                   1.0  
48860                   0.0  
27429                   0.0  
13414                   1.0  
8730                     1.0  

these are the first rows of y_train, there are rows that belongs to one and rows to 0

Comment: Ah ok so your counter is the problem

Comment: with shuffle=True and 25% counter is:
Counter({0: 12761})
if I print the variable labels it contains only zero

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see, what are you set on 'y' for train_test_split?

Comment: Yes ok, you said to me that you have person belongs to cluster1 in your y_train, but that's not say that you have person belongs to 1 in your y_test

Comment: of course I have, because I have a dataset (called newTotalDataset) that has 50% rows belongs to 1 and 50% to 0.
If I split in training and test, in the worst case I could have training with all 0 or all 1, and my test will have 1 and 0 (not in the same perceptual, but it has both)

Comment: Kmeans is an unsupervised machine learning algorithms, so you can't know clusters before. Maybe you want to perform a supervised classification?
Please show me your the head of your  newTotalDataset

Comment: Ok so you don't use the good algorithms. Look for a classifier because you want to perform supervised learning

Comment: Thanks you so much!
before using newTotalDataset to split it in training and test I removed "identifier" feature. Should I use this dataset (and not newTotalDataset) for unsupervised?

Comment: You could do the same but for fit classifier you will have to put X_train and Y_train 
like that `.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: well if my answer is right please mark it as accepted ...(past 15 minutes) see how [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)